# Will a Raspberry Pi 3 case fit a Raspberry Pi 2 B?

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, case, compatibility

I've gotten a Raspberry Pi 2B as a gift, but without a case. I'm trying to buy me a case, but I mostly find Pi 3 cases being offered.

So, I'm asking the opposite of this question: [Is the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B or B+ case compatible with the Raspberry Pi 3?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/44446/88531)

I understand that there might be some issue with the LEDs, so I should prefer a transparent case. Can I be sure there are no other incompatibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only significant physical difference in the positioning of the ACT/PWR LEDs.

I have cases with LED cutouts on both sides.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, screw holes & dimensions are the same. I know this from experience.

Comment: "Yes", that is to say  there won't be any issues other than the LED's location?